# multiple components with tables in one page with a same @HostListener keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-table

i have multiple components in the same page with table inside. Each of these table has a @HostListener waiting for the "Ctr + B" keyboard shortcut to be pressed when this happens a row added in the specific table. How i can focus in specific table ? with my current implementation row added to all tables in the same time

```
    @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent($event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let keyCode = $event.key;


        if(($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) && keyCode == '\x02') {
            console.log('CTRL + B');
            this.onAdd();
        }

        console.log($event);
    }
```

Comment: When `you` press ctrlB, what table would `I` want? You need to read my mind to answer that question. If you don't have that ability, then I have to tell you exactly what table I wanted, something like: hey select me the first table, or the last table...

Comment: i want to add a row in the "the focused tabled"

Comment: so far I can only think of 2 ways: you have to click on a table so that Angular knows that's "the focused tabled" . The other way is to detect the currently focusing element, check if that's the table you want. Though, I can only implement for the first workaround, I don't know how to detect focusing element